# Dropping Empty Lists from Nested List

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

So I have a function which returns a List which contains either empty lists or Series. I loop through a list of tickers and for each it will return a empty list or Series and store them inside one list.

However, after looping through all I want to be able to drop the empty lists and only have the Series within the list.

```
def get_revenue_growth(ticker) -> pd.DataFrame:

income_statement_annually = fa.financial_statement_growth(ticker, FA_API_KEY, period="annual")

if  'revenueGrowth' in income_statement_annually.index:
    
    revenue_growth = income_statement_annually.loc['revenueGrowth']
    exchange_df = pd.DataFrame({ticker : revenue_growth})        
    exchange_df.index = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(exchange_df.index))
    exchange_df = exchange_df[exchange_df.index.year >= 1998]
    exchange_df = exchange_df.sort_index()
    
    print('Getting Revenue Growth for ' + ticker + ': Passed')
    
else:
    print('Getting Revenue Growth for ' + ticker + ': Failed')
    
    exchange_df = []
    
return exchange_df
```

This is the function I am calling via this:

```
revenue_growth = [get_revenue_growth(t) for t in tickers]
```

[Here is what the output looks like...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQLlR.png)

So what I am trying to achieve is to remove all the empty lists. I tried this `list2 = [x for x in list1 if x != []]` but it did not work.

Comment: Try:  `list2 = [x for x in list1 if x]`

Comment: Or this list2 = [x for x in list1 if len(x)>0]

Comment: @JonSG I tried this earlier, sadly get the error ```ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```

Comment: Let me add the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply solve it via:

```
list2 = [x for x in list1 if len(x)>0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at this Example -

```
mylist = [] 

if len(mylist) == 0:
    del mylist # Deletes the Empty List
else:
    # Do Something else
```

Modify this piece for your program